# Map a list of functions over a list of arguments (Python)

Tags: python, functional-programming, cartesian-product

I have a list of functions:  listFunc=[g1, g2, g3].  This list is generated with the code below:

```
def g(y): 
    def f(x):
        return x+y;
    return f; 
listFunc=list(map(g, [1, 2, 3]));
```

Now, I have a list of arguments ListArg = [4, 5, 6];

How could I get a result list of `[g1(4), g1(5), g1(6), g2(4), g2(5), g2(6), g3(4), g3(5), g3(6)]` using `map` only?

I thought about using the following code:

```
map(lambda x:x(y), listFunc, ListArg)
```

But it only gives a result of `[g1(4), g2(5), g3(6)]`.

Thanks,

Comment: For future reference, what you want is called the "Cartesian Product". For some (non-python) discussion see http://phrogz.net/lazy-cartesian-product

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a perfect use-case for a list comprehension with two for-clauses:

```
>>> def g1(x): return 1*x
... 
>>> def g2(x): return 2*x
... 
>>> def g3(x): return 3*x
... 
>>> funcs = [g1,g2,g3]
>>> args = [4,5,6]
>>> [f(a) for f in funcs for a in args]
[4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 12, 15, 18]
>>>
```

This is eminently readable and eminently functional - list comprehensions were borrowed from Haskell.

If you feel some deep need to use map, then you will have to approach it like this:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(map(lambda f,a : f(a), *zip(*itertools.product(funcs,args))))
[4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 12, 15, 18]
```

Which is eminently *unreadable* and likely slower. List comprehensions win here.

Comment: Somehow, I kept reading into the question that the OP knew about list comprehensions, but wanted to use `map` anyway.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use `map()`, you could do:

```
>>> [k for item in map(lambda x: [g(x) for g in listFunc], ListArg) for k in item]
[5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Your `listFunc` and `ListArg` are swapped. Your code computes `g1(4), g2(4), ...` when `g1(4), g1(5), ...` was originally desired. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can't quite do this with *just* `map`, but you can nest one call in another, and use `sum` to flatten the result.

```
>>> sum(map(lambda x : map(lambda f: f(x), ListArg),listFunc), [])
[5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: +1 because I love this answer. However, your maps are backward; the desired output is g1(4), g1(5), g1(6), g2(4), g2(5), ..., but your code executes g1(4), g2(4), g3(4), g1(5), g2(5), ...

Comment: Ah, tricky because `+` is commutative :) Just needed to swap the two lists.

Answer (score 3):

[itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) helps

```
def g(y): 
    def f(x):
        return x+y
    return f
funcs = map(g, [1, 2, 3])
args = [4,5,6]
p = itertools.product(funcs, args)
r = [f(arg) for f, arg in p]
```

---

The only alternative to the list comprehension I could come up with is:

```
def foo(args):
    f, a = args
    return f(a)
r = list(map(foo, p)) # using p from above
```

Comment: Never mind, i somehow saw something that wasn't there. I'm going to delete my comments for clarity. You may wish to do the same.